# MySQL database in tasksel LAMP stack for osCommerce

Tags: mysql, webserver

I'm experimenting with osCommerce, an e-commerce suite, for which I installed the LAMP stack using `tasksel`. It did ask for a "root password" for MySQL, but other that that I did not pay attention to the installation procedure. Now I'm faced with the following screen, with no idea with what goes where:

[image]

So my question is what are the default options, and how do I find all the details?

Comment: Maybe the default values are the same as here: http://library.linode.com/web-applications/e-commerce/oscommerce/ubuntu-9.10-karmic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should create a MySQL user for osCommerce to use. It's bad practise to use the root user/pass for a web application.

In a shell on the machine with the MySQL on it, do:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Enter the root password you previously specified. This gets you a prompt which has full access to your mysql server.

Now, pick a database name - it doesn't matter what it is really so long as it's unique on the mysql server (to see existing ones: `SHOW DATABASES;`)

When you've decided on it:

```
CREATE DATABASE dbname;
```

For example, I'd probably just pick `oscommerce`.

Now you have to give a new user access to that database. Pick a username and password (the username can be `oscommerce` again, but make a secure password) - replace `dbname` here with what you chose a second ago:

```
GRANT ALL ON dbname.* TO username IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Done. Now you have the details to put into your webform; the servername is just `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` (assuming the webserver is the same machine as the MySQL server), the user and password you just made, the database name is whatever you replaced `dbname` with. Port can be left empty.

Answer (score 1):

Database server: 127.0.0.1 (if it is on the same computer, else the ip address of the remote host)

user name: ny MySQL user name. If you just set up mysql you should login to mysql on the local host and setup a user for your project (use the mysql commant in terminal). I do not suggest to use the database root user, however, this should work as well:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

follow these instructions:

[adding users](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/adding-users.html)

Password: the password of the user specified before

Database Name: on your mysql database server there exists no database. So again, login into mysql, but this time with the user you just created. Then follow these instructions to generate a database. You then have to fill in the database name in your form:

[Create Database](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/create-database.html)

Database Server Port: leave empty should work. Keep the other settings as they are.

Comment: I assumed, that you have basic SQL knowledge. If not ask again as a comment!

Comment: sorry Michael I basically duped your answer, but it took me ages to type so I'm leaving it if that's ok :p

Comment: you are a slow-typer :-D pwned

Comment: You should summarize the steps in your answers, like @Caesium did, instead of just linking to avoid issues with link rot. The links can be mentioned in the end as references. (Personally, I like to avoid traversing and reading through linked articles if the instructions are already there (unless I want to know the details), so I'll refer to Caesium's answers for the steps)

Comment: unsure about this... the link is official mysql homepage, which ensures, that the information keep up to date on change. Further I want to encourage users, to read the background and find out how it works, instead of stupid copy and paste of commands.

Comment: Official MySQL page is also an issue. Ubuntu generally sticks with the same version throughout the life of a release, it does not keep up-to-date with upstream except for security fixes. And nobody knows when a site (in general, not referring to MySQL.com) can go down - posting the steps here will keep the answer relevant. And well, I generally do read background info, but most people do not need to (that being the ease-of-use point of Ubuntu), they can set up osCommerce with just those commands. The references are there so they can check if they need to something more later.

Comment: You can read the official SE stance on this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259

Answer (score 0):

If you dont know the password, maybe it is just blank. If dont, to reset the root password you can follow this guide: [MySQL Doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html#resetting-permissions-unix). 
Database server is `localhost` unless you have osCommerce and MySQL in different machines. For username you could use `root`, but if you use this in a production environment, using a more limited user will be better. Password is the password you choose during reset process.
To create the database, you can login to mysql (remove -p switch if password is blank):

```
mysql -u root -p
```

And then use the following statement to show the databases in the system:

```
mysql > CREATE DATABASE the_name_you_want;
```

Server port is `3306`.