# File permissions to let web application write files

Tags: webserver

I installed osCommerce using [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81021/how-do-i-install-oscommerce/81290#81290). During the initial run, I was asked to point at the MySQL database it should use and set up admin accounts. But to save the settings, it needed to modify an existing file:

> The webserver was not able to write the installation parameters to its
>   configuration file due to file permission problems.
>
> Please verify the file permissions of the configuration file and try
>   again by clicking on the Retry button below.
>
> The configuration file is located at:
>
> `/var/www/oscommerce/osCommerce/OM/Config/settings.ini`

What permission setting do I need to enable the web application to write, on what files, and how?

**NB** I can edit the file in question and save the settings manually, but to avoid issues in the future, I want to know how to let the web application run as it should.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The webserver runs as the user `www-data`.

To let it modify a file, just change the owner of that file to `www-data`, like so:

```
chown www-data /var/www/oscommerce/osCommerce/OM/Config/settings.ini
```

For security purposes I would recommended chowning as few things as possible - in fact afterwards, when it's done, you could even chown it back to the original owner so that the webserver can't write to it again.

`ls -l` will show you the current owner of a file, ie:

```
ls -l /var/www/oscommerce/osCommerce/OM/Config/settings.ini
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 200 2011-11-15 17:17 /var/www/oscommerce/osCommerce/OM/Config/settings.ini
```

Here the owner is `root` (the second `root` is the group-owner of the file).

There are other ways to grant the webserver write-access, such as setting the file world-writeable, but this has other inherent dangers (ANYONE could change your config) and I wouldn't recommend that.